# C# LINQ to Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a set of LINQ results as follows:

```
var dictionaryHere = db.tbl_user_pass_list
      .Where(e => e.Usage1 == "Domain Administrator");
```

This returns a number of properties, of which I need the AdminUsername and AdminPassword and Company.

I have a class setup for this:

```
public class AdminUsernamePassword
{
    public string AdminUsername { get; set; }
    public string AdminPassword { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to generate is a dictionary where the Key is company, and the value contains AdminUsername and AdminPassword. I've got as far as this:

```
 Dictionary<string, AdminUsernamePassword> dictionary = dictionaryHere.ToDictionary(o => o.Company,
```

I'm not sure how to complete this though to get my two other values in as the AdminUsernamePassword type. Any help appreciated!

Comment: `.ToDictionary(o => o.Company, x => new AdminUserPassword(x.UserName, x.Password)`? I assumed a ctor with `username` and `password` to keep it short.

Comment: @germi Should have been an answer.

Comment: @Magnus right, I added it as an answer

Comment: Not posting this as an answer since it doesn't answer the question, but be sure that the Adminpassword is properly secured: encrypt it while it's in the Dictionary, and don't decrypt it until you actually need it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to specify your `Value` of the `KeyValuePair`. You already have the key:

```
dictionaryHere.ToDictionary(o => o.Company, [...])
```

You just need to create your `Value`:

```
dictionaryHere.ToDictionary(o => o.Company, 
                            x => new AdminUserPassword 
                            { 
                              AdminUserName = x.UserName, 
                              AdminPassword = x.Password 
                            });
```